# Using Greasemonkey to execute Javascript every 5 seconds?

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey

I am new to Greasemonkey and javascript but have found the script below, I want to execute it every 5 seconds.

```
javascript:$('.comments-stream .more:not(.dnone)').parent().find('.fa-minus').parent() .click();
```

Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `setInterval`. Notice how i removed the parentheses from the click function.

```
javascript:setInterval($('.comments-stream .more:not(.dnone)').parent().find('.fa-minus').parent() .click, 5000);
```

If you want to do more then just the click.

```
javascript:setInterval(function(){
    $('.comments-stream .more:not(.dnone)').parent().find('.fa-minus').parent() .click();
, 5000);
```